# Running a batch file from task scheduler and getting access denied

Tags: windows-8, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to run a batch file from Windows 8 Task scheduler and I'm getting an access denied error on the command prompt for the following command line.

```
echo "Hello World" >> C:\File.txt
```

However, if I tick the checkbox "Run with higest privileges" under the task scheduler then it works fine.

The question is why do I require to tick the checkbox when I can run the batch manually without the "Run as administrator"?

Answer (score 2):

A couple possibilities:

If a task is registered using the Administrators group for the security context of the task, then you must also make sure the Run with highest privileges check box is checked if you want to run the task.

If you are using the S4U functionality, make sure the Logon as batch job policy is set for the user.

Make sure the user account the task is using has write access to the C:\ directory

Answer (score 1):

By default in modern Windows you cannot write to the root directory.  Use "%temp%\file.txt" instead.